# Limit the numerical value in a MultiLine TextBox

Tags: asp.net

The requirement is :

In a Multiline text box, user should be able to add either `8-digit numerical number` or `10-digit numerical number` separated by commas.

```
Example: 1234567891,2345678911, and so on....
```

There is no limit on the overall length of text box , but the numerical values within the text box should be either 8 or 10.

I have already written the code for limiting numerical values, but don't know how to restrict values with in the text box.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: "I have already written the code for limiting numerical values." Show us :)

Comment: Protected Sub txt_ipo_po_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txt_ipo_po.TextChanged

        If IsNumeric(Me.txt_ipo_po.Text) Then
            Me.lbl_IPO_PO.Text = ""
        Else
            Me.lbl_IPO_PO.Text = "Must be a number!"
            txt_ipo_po.Text = ""
        End If

    End Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use regular expression validator for the same.

Below is the regular expressions :

**For Only 10 digits :**

```
^[0-9]{10}( *, *[0-9]{10})*$
```

**For Either 8 or 10 digits :**

```
^(\d{8}|\d{10})( *, *(\d{8}|\d{10}))*$
```

Comment: The solution that you have provided works.

 But the error message is displayed only for very few secs. I want to display the error for more time . How can I do that .

Comment: this is not the behavior of the regular expression validator. By default error message stays there and it will not go. May be some javascript or code has been implemented to remove the error message after few seconds. Check that code and try to update it.

Comment: Noooo,

Error message is not staying there . It flashes and then disappears. I don't want it to disappear so quickly

Comment: <asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" AutoPostBack="true" Rows="2" Columns="80" ID="txt_ipo_po"  runat="server"
                                    CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{10}( *, *[0-9]{10})*$" w ControlToValidate="txt_ipo_po" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Must be either 8-digit or 10-digit"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>          
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_IPO_PO" runat="server" Style="color: #FF0000" Text=""></asp:Label>

Comment: Protected Sub txt_ipo_po_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txt_ipo_po.TextChanged

        If IsNumeric(Me.txt_ipo_po.Text) Then
            Me.lbl_IPO_PO.Text = ""
        Else
            Me.lbl_IPO_PO.Text = "Must be a number!"
            txt_ipo_po.Text = ""
        End If

    End Sub

Comment: It is coming like this only , Don't know how to put in a proper way

Comment: No problem :) Remove the **AutoPostBack="true"** from textbox and remove the event **txt_ipo_po_TextChanged** from your code. Because there is no need to check for this as our regular expression will always allow comma separated numbers. if it is alphabetic characters then regular expression validator will display error message.

Comment: Super !!!!!!!!! I removed both of them :D , It works. Thanks a million ....... Great :D :D

Comment: Hiiii , It is working for 10 digit numbers perfectly, But for 8 digit numbers it is working some times only :( :( :( dnt know why

Comment: Noooooooooooo, I want to allow either 8 or 10 digit number example : 12345678 : shd be accepted 1234567891 : shd be accepted . Both 8 and 9 digit numbers shd be accepted. PLease do something :( :(

Comment: If you want to allow either 8 or 10 digit then use this regular expression : **^(\d{8}|\d{10})( *, *(\d{8}|\d{10}))*$**

Comment: You are a Savior :D :D :D God bless u :D